# Can't pass array via Ajax to Django view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I'm new with ajax and I want to pass array which is in java script to my view.

this is my template.I have one form that take course IDnumber and course score from student and create table and add how many course,student want to add.

I have one variable named "stock" in javascript. "stock" store all selected course 's idnumber and score. I want to send stock to view to add selected course to database. I use Ajax for doing it but it doesn't work an get "error doing something".

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head >

<title>Add new course</title>
{% load staticfiles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'student/css1.css' %}" /> 
{% include "student/base.html" %}   
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="metric_results">
<div id="form">
   <form name="myForm"   method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.non_field_errors }}
                <div id="form-data">
                {{ form.course_id }}{{ form.course_id.errors }}
                <label for="id_course_id">ID number:</label><br>

                {{ form.score }}{{ form.score.errors }}
                <label for="id_score">score:</label><br>
                <p id="add_button"><input type="button" value="add"  /></p>
                <p><input type="submit" value="submit" /></p>
                </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div id="table">
    <table id="TABLE" border = '1'>


    </table>
    </div>



<script type="text/javascript">
    //when click on "add" button,call "addTable" function.
    document.getElementById("add_button").onclick = function() {addTable()};
    document.getElementById("delete_button").onclick = function() {DeleteTableRow()};

    var stock = new Array();
    var i = 0;

    function addTable() {

        var id = document.forms["myForm"]["course_id"].value;
        var score = document.forms["myForm"]["score"].value;
        var c = document.createElement("INPUT");
        var heading = new Array();
        c.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
        stock[i] = new Array(id, score);
        //table heading
        heading=["idnumber","score","delete"];
        //check Is there selected course in table
        for(j=0; j<i; j++){if (stock[j][0] == id){alert("this course was selected.");}}


        //Get the table that shows the selected course from html code
        var table = document.getElementById('TABLE');
        //At first create table heading
        if(i==0){
        var tr = document.createElement('TR');
        for(j=0;j<3;j++){
        var th = document.createElement('TH');

        th.appendChild(document.createTextNode(heading[j]));
        tr.appendChild(th);}

        table.appendChild(tr);}

        //Create table row and append it to end of table
        var tr = document.createElement('TR');
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                var td = document.createElement('TD');
                if(j == 2){
                    td.setAttribute("id","check_box"+(i+1));
                    td.appendChild(c);}
                else{
                    td.setAttribute("id","rows"+(i+1));
                    td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(stock[i][j]));}
                tr.appendChild(td);
                }

        table.appendChild(tr);
        document.forms["myForm"]["course_id"].value="";
        document.forms["myForm"]["score"].value="";  
        i=i+1;
    }


var postUrl = "http://localhost:8000/student/{{id}}/student_add_course/";
$('form[name="myForm"]').submit(function(){
$.ajax({
url:postUrl,
type: "POST",
data: {'stock': stock},
error:function (xhr, textStatus, thrownError){
    alert("error doing something");
},
})
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

this is my view:

```
def student_add_course(request,student_id):
    if request.method=='GET':
        context={'id':student_id , 'form':AddCourseForStudentForm()}
        request.session['ListOfCourses']=[]
        return render(request, 'student/AddCourseForStudentForm.html',context)
    elif request.method=='POST':
        print request.POST.getlist('stock[]')
        return render(request, 'student/add_course.html')
```

What is wrong with code? Is there any better way to do this?

I'm be happy if someone help me.

I'm sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Do `alert(thrownError);` instead to see what the error is.

Comment: I do that and say FORBIDDEN

Comment: @user3789719 You need to pass csrf token since you're doing ajax POST request.

Comment: @mariodev thanks for your answer.Could you explain how pass crf token?

Answer (score 0):

First of all try to turn off csrf protection for your view:

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def student_add_course(request,student_id):
```

If it will help, read about passing csrf in AJAX here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/#ajax